# Flash stop "actionscript error" dialog box from appearing

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I need to disable flash from showing these error messages when an error occurs.  I am completely aware of the error I'm receiving, and it does not cause my application from working correctly.  I simply need to disable these messages.  Is there a setting in flash or a flex compiler command or something?  Thanks, David.

Comment: Add SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1 to the mm.cfg file did it for me, see also: http://www.senocular.com/?entry=475

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there's no such thing. Though, the errors will not be displayed to users that have the release version of the flash player installed, and not the debugger one.

There's a very hot feature request for the flash player but the implementation seems far from happening: [Ability to intercept system error dialogs](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-444). There are a lot of comments some heated, some sarcastic but Adobe seems to still ignore this issue.

**UPDATE**
The feature has since been implemented. Last comment says:

> This has been fixed with Flash player 10.1
>   http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/features.html
>
> Global error handler The new global error handler enables developers
>   to write a single handler to process all runtime errors that were not
>   part of a try/catch statement. Improve application reliability and
>   user experience by catching and handling unexpected runtime errors and
>   present custom error messages. When using the global error handler in
>   a SWF running in the debug player, error pop-ups will not be shown.

Comment: Add SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1 to the mm.cfg file did it for me, see also: http://www.senocular.com/?entry=475

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things you can do with your mm.cfg file (google it's usage)

For instance if you put:

SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1

In there it will prevent the debugger version of flash from popping up error windows in your browser.

Comment: Add SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1 to the mm.cfg file did it for me, see also: http://www.senocular.com/?entry=475